# PHPExcel Is there any way to validate input date in dd-mm-yyyy format?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have following code for reading data from .xls file.

```html
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(false);

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

$chunksize=_CHUNKSIZE_;
$endRow=$chunksize;
$count=ceil($highestRow/$chunksize);

for ($row=1;$row<=$endRow;$row++)
        {
            if($row>$highestRow){
                break;
            }
            for ($col=0;$col<$highestColumnIndex;$col++)
            {
                $cellobj=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                $value=$cellobj->getValue();
                if(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cellobj)) { //to check the date
                    $value=$cellobj->getFormattedValue();
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Here it returns the date in 'mm-dd-yyyy' format when in any date is provided in any format. I actually need to validate that the date should be in the 'dd-mm-yyyy'.

Comment: What format mask is used for the cells containing dates?

Comment: @MarkBaker Hi.. I've tried using the 'Custom' format that is 'dd-mm-yyyy', even with 'Text' too. I only want to prevent the data which has Invalid Date Format.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use

```
if(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cellobj)) { //to check the date
    $value=$cellobj->getFormattedValue();
}
```

to verify if a cell contains a date, and convert it to a string formatted using the cells format mask, use

```
if(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cellobj)) { //to check the date
    $datetimeobj = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($cellobj->getValue());
}
```

and you can then use the [DateTime object's](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) [format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method to format it however you want

Comment: Hi there.. The problem over here is that this returns me the valid date. Technically correct. But I need the user not to input date except the 'dd-mm-yyyy' format. I rather have a doubt that my requirement can be met or not,,

Comment: That's up to what the user might do in Excel itself, not with PHPExcel.... if you control the spreadsheet that they're editing/creating, you might be able to create dropdowns for day, month and year and then combine those three values with a formula that converts them to a  date

Comment: So, you are saying that it can be done from the spreadsheet only not with PHPExcel, There is no alternate way to do this.

Comment: If you need the user to input dates to the spreadsheet using MS Excel, and you subsequently load the spreadsheet using PHPExcel, and you need the users to input dates in a specific format..... then it has to be done at the point where the user does that input (ie MS Excel).... they've already entered the date (right format or otherwise) at the point where you load it into PHPExcel

Comment: But if a user has entered a date, a value that's recognised as a date by MS Excel itself, then it's a serialized timestamp, so the code that I've posted above should work irrespective of the format that it's been entered in